# How to split only first name from string data?

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split string data, but only the first name.

```
data = '111222333 Hello, some example!'
```

(split)

```
namber = '111222333'
data = 'Hello, some example'
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

To only split once, look into maxsplit parameter of [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
data = '111222333 Hello, some example!'
number, text = data.split(maxsplit=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
data = '111222333 Hello, some example!'
```

First we split the string and save it as a list.

```
data_lst = data.split()
print(data_lst)
```

Then, you select the first item of the list (element 0 of the list).

```
print(data_lst[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data='111222333 Hello, some example!'
ind=None
for i,s in enumerate(data):
     if s.isalpha():     #to detect the letter
         ind=i         # holding the i value in ind.
         break         
number,data=int(data[:ind].strip()), data[ind:].strip() #strip to remove side spaces.
print(number, data, sep='\n')
```

> use the Slicing operator for the Separating or splitting string. The syntax for the slicing operator would be:`string_name[starting_index : ending_index+1: step(optional)]`. if starting index is not mentioned then it takes as 0 and if the end isn't mentioned then until end string got printed.